# How to control a TV from Linux?

Tags: linux, hdmi, tv

I have an always-on Linux server (Ubuntu 15.10) connected via HDMI to a TV. I would like to ultimately get rid of the TV remote and use a wireless keyboard only (which I use today to control `kodi` running on that PC).

Is it possible to use HDMI-CEC **from the Linux to the TV**  to send an on/off command? (I have not thought the *how* through yet, but probably by binding specific keys to the keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it if the server and the TV support CEC.  Your TV may have disable it by default and use a different name for it meaning you will have to find it and turn it on (Here is a guide on enabling CEC on TVs http://www.howtogeek.com/207186/how-to-enable-hdmi-cec-on-your-tv-and-why-you-should/).
The Embedded Linux Wiki also has a page on [using CEC with the Raspberry Pi](http://elinux.org/CEC_%28Consumer_Electronics_Control%29_over_HDMI) that lists the programs and libraries might use with your computer to control the TV.